# VS 2010 multiproject solutions: global/local \bin dll's clashing?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a multi project solution ( 2 apps, 3 class libraries) which includes a global `\bin` folder that all the projects build their dll's to.

Each project also has its own local `\bin`. If I make a change in one of the apps, I run into an error that source code is different from original version.

I believe that this is because rebuilding the solution after the change updates the global `\bin` assembly but not the local one. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Where is the global bin stored? When you say "local bin" are you refering to the individual bin folders of each project or are you refering to the bin folders stored on your local machine? In either case i would see if excluding the individual project bins from the project and only having the global bin does the trick. This way they aren't able to trip over each other. I'm not 100% sure on this solution though which is why it isn't an answer, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: Have you got "Copy Local" turned on for your references?  And are you using project or binary references?

Comment: @Tony318 Yes, by local bin I mean the individual bin folders. I tried emptying the individual bins... but as I found, local bin is where `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` refers to and I don't know of a way to tell .NET to change where it gets executing assemblies from. Suggestions?

Comment: @DanPuzey I am using project references and yes "Copy Local" is turned on.

Comment: @Tony318 Oh..and the global bin is on the same machine...may be a better name would be "common bin". Sorry about that.

Comment: @Sinthia don't remove the files from it. Let it act normally as it would. What you should do is just right click on it and select "Exclude from project". As for your "common bin" make sure that is included in the project by doing the same thing. Again i still don't know if that will work but i do know that i've ran into problems with Visual Source Safe when i have local bins included in projects. It may be a similar result with having a global bin.